# GNU make ignores Implicit rules

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile some C++ sources with GNU make using implicit rules, here's the content of my Makefile:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $<
```

and the output of `make`

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Running `make -d` isn't very helping (I don't post the output which is quite verbose other than apparently useless). The folder is not empty.

Comment: If that's your entire makefile and you just ran `make` you haven't told make *what* to compile. Try `make somebin` where you have a `somebin.cpp` file or add `all: somebin` to your makefile and run `make`. You need to actually tell make *what* targets/etc. to build.

Comment: @StefanoCampanella _I'm trying to compile some C++ sources with GNU make using implicit rules_ No you're not since you have explicitely overridden the implicit rule. At this point you can delete your Makefile altogether and build a file directly using `make somefile.o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told `make` how to create arbitrary `.o` files from corresponding `.cpp` files, but you didn't tell it *which* files to create.

Analogy: I tell you, that, say, to make USB sticks, you'll need plastic, memory chips and a USB-A plug (now you know how to create *any* USB stick). But I don't say *which* USB sticks to create. This is exactly, what's happening here.

To solve your issue, you can say to `make` to create (for example) "asdf.o" by invoking `make asdf.o`, and it'll gladly do so, by using `g++ -o asdf.o asdf.cpp`.
You can also add an (*de facto standard*) `all` target, like so:

```
all: asdf.o fdsa.o [you get it]
```

And since the first target is the default, calling `make` is equivalent to calling `make all`, which in turn requires "asdf.o" and "fdsa.o", which will be created as described above.

Answer (score 4):

You told Make how to build `.o` files, but you didn't tell it:

- to build any `.o` files;
- which `.o` files to build;
- what to do with those `.o` files afterwards.

The rule doesn't mean that, when invoked without arguments, all `.cpp` files in the current directory or something will be compiled.

This one rule is just not enough.